# why cv::cuda::createMedianFilter function is slower than cv::medianBlur?

Tags: opencv, gpu, opencv3.1

As you know, `Ptr<Filter> cv::cuda::createMedianFilter (int srcType, int windowSize, int partition=128)` function added to OpenCV3.1.0.

I'm trying to do a median filter on 8 bit large images (6000*6000) with custom window size(up to 21). I compare `cv::medianBlur` and `cv::cuda::createMedianFilter` and results was

```
windowSize    cv::medianBlur    cv::cuda::createMedianFilter
    3             0.071 sec         3.637 sec
    5             0.285 sec         3.679 sec
    11            2.641 sec         3.652 sec
    19            2.566 sec         3.719 sec
```

1) why cuda::createMedianFilter is slower than cv::medianBlur?

2) How can i write a kernel code to implement median filter that use opencv Mat with custom kernel size?

Comment: for questions 2, which one do you want to ask? How to write CUDA code, or only how to write CUDA convolution code?

Comment: @kangshiyins How to write CUDA convolution code

Answer (score 1):

The speed of the the convolution operation mainly depends on the size of the filter kernel when is image size is constant. Considering sorting is more complicated than summation, median filter will cost longer time.

To go down to low level  to implement your own CUDA convolution function with customized filter kernel， you need to get the raw pointer of your image data

```
MyConv(char* image, int width, int height, int stride)
```

and then writing CUDA code.

Here's a tutorial on cuda convolution.

http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~biri/Enseignement/MII2/Donnees/convolutionSeparable.pdf

This question also gives an example.

[cuda convolution mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096915/cuda-convolution-mapping/)

Comment: Thank kangshiyin, in both OpenCV functions (medianBlur and createMedianFilter) we can set kernelSize. can you clearly answer to second question?

Comment: @amirhossein do you mean "custom kernel" rather than "custom kernel size"?

Comment: @kangshiyins custom kernel size mean: kernel radius, like 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15. custom kernel like kernel with 5*5, that is fill whit '1' like triangle top or triangle bottom or even only third row. for example with kernel with 5*5 and third row fill with '1', only 5 element of 25 kernel elements are '1'

Comment: @amirhossein I know but which one do you want to know in your q2? You wrote "custom kernel size" but I thought it would be "custom kernel"

Comment: @kangshiyins for a first version, kernel size be 15*15 with circle kernel shape. in this case, 157 pixel fill with '1'

Comment: @amirhossein I see. You may want to amend your question, it looks confusing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116333/discussion-between-amir-hossein-and-kangshiyin).

Comment: The median filter **does not** perform a convolution. It is a non-linear filter where the median of an array is computed. So instead of convolving, the complexity relies on sorting the data.

Answer (score 1):

I also used `cuda::createMedianFilter()` and found that, there are two GpuMat newly allocated in `MedianFilter::apply()` everytime calling `filter->apply()`, and GPU memory allocation is very time consuming, so I move the two Mats into MedianFilter Class to be member vars(do not allocated again unless the images size changes).

Speed up 4X tested with 1000 images (400 * 300). Also, it seems like the parameter partitions could be set to src.rows / 2, which will be faster than the original parameter-128.

The two mat in [src code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/1a0282df21d9e393bfc7089d673361dd15b5ecea#diff-33a8350111f1f6d7cfb266136b211f4f) are `GpuMat devHist; GpuMat devCoarseHist`